# How to implement a multi-label text classifier in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I've been trying to create a multi-label text classifier that uses GloVe embeddings using Keras. I'm currently experimenting with the TREC-6 data set available at http://cogcomp.org/Data/QA/QC/. I'm only considering the 5 broad labels for my classification problem and am ignoring the sub-labels.

Since it's a multi-label classification problem, given a sentence, my neural network should output all labels with a probability greater than 0.1. Issue is that the network almost always classifies a question with only 1 label, which is fine when I'm asking a question that belongs to only one category. When I combine questions from different categories however, it still gives only one label with a high confidence most of the time, although I want all relevant labels to be identified.
I'm absolutely sure the pre-processing steps are correct. I get the feeling that there's some issue in my model.

I started experimenting with only CNNs in the beginning by referring to the paper "Convolutional Neural Networks for Sentence Classification" at https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D14-1181.pdf, but on a teacher's advice and after seeing that they fail for long questions with different relevant topics, I tried experimenting with LSTMs and BiLSTMS. I started with this approach https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-insincere-questions-classification/discussion/80568 and kept modifying some parameters / adding and removing layers hoping to get a good result but I've failed so far.
I tried copy pasting some code for Attention mechanism and adding that after my LSTM layers as well but it doesn't help.

My current model looks somewhat like this. I'll paste most of the rest of my code for clarity. The model and training code is present in the sentence_classifier() function.

```
class SentenceClassifier:
    def __init__(self):
        self.MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 200
        self.EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
        self.LABEL_COUNT = 0
        self.WORD_INDEX = dict()
        self.LABEL_ENCODER = None

    def clean_str(self, string):
        """
        Cleans each string and convert to lower case.
        """

        string = re.sub(r"\'s", "", string)
        string = re.sub(r"\'ve", "", string)
        string = re.sub(r"n\'t", " not", string)
        string = re.sub(r"\'re", "", string)
        string = re.sub(r"\'d", "", string)
        string = re.sub(r"\'ll", "", string)
        string = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9]", " ", string)
        string = re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", string)

        return string.strip().lower()

    def loader_encoder(self, table, type="json"):
        """
        Load and encode data from dataset.

        type = "sql" means get data from MySQL database.
        type = "json" means get data from .json file.        """

        if type == "json":
            with open('data/' + table + '.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
                datastore = json.load(f)
                questions = []
                tags = []
                for row in datastore:
                    questions.append(row['question'])
                    tags.append(row['tags'].split(','))

        tokenizer = Tokenizer(lower=True, char_level=False)
        tokenizer.fit_on_texts(questions)
        self.WORD_INDEX = tokenizer.word_index

        questions_encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(questions)
        questions_encoded_padded = pad_sequences(questions_encoded, maxlen=self.MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, padding='post')


        for i, ele in enumerate(tags):
            for j, tag in enumerate(ele):
                if len(tag) == 0 or tag == ',':
                    del tags[i][j]


        encoder = MultiLabelBinarizer()
        encoder.fit(tags)
        self.LABEL_ENCODER = encoder
        tags_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(tags)
        self.LABEL_COUNT = len(tags_encoded[0]) #No. of labels
        print("\tUnique Tokens in Training Data: ", len(self.WORD_INDEX))


        return questions_encoded_padded, tags_encoded

    def load_embeddings(self, EMBED_PATH='./embeddings/glove.6B.100d.txt'):
        """
        Load pre-trained embeddings into memory.
        """
        embeddings_index = {}
        try:
            f = open(EMBED_PATH, encoding='utf-8')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Embeddings missing.")
            sys.exit()
        for line in f:
            values = line.rstrip().rsplit(' ')
            word = values[0]
            vec = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
            embeddings_index[word] = vec
        f.close()
        print("\tNumber of tokens in embeddings file: ", len(embeddings_index))
        return embeddings_index

    def create_embedding_matrix(self, embeddings_index):
        """
        Creates an embedding matrix for all the words(vocab) in the training data with shape (vocab, EMBEDDING_DIM).
        Out-of-vocab words will be randomly initialized to values between +0.25 and -0.25.
        """
        words_not_found = []
        vocab = len(self.WORD_INDEX) + 1
        embedding_matrix = np.random.uniform(-0.25, 0.25, size=(vocab, self.EMBEDDING_DIM))
        for word, i in self.WORD_INDEX.items():
            if i >= vocab:
                continue
            embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
            if (embedding_vector is not None) and len(embedding_vector) > 0:
                embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
            else:
                words_not_found.append(word)
        # print('Number of null word embeddings: %d' % np.sum(np.sum(embedding_matrix, axis=1) == 0))
        print("\tShape of embedding matrix: ", str(embedding_matrix.shape))
        print("\tNo. of words not found in pre-trained embeddings: ", len(words_not_found))
        return embedding_matrix

    def sentence_classifier_cnn(self, embedding_matrix, x, y, table, load_saved=0):
        """
        A static CNN model.
        Makes uses of Keras functional API for constructing the model.

        If load_saved=1, THEN load old model, ELSE train new model


        model_name = table + ".model.h5"
        if load_saved == 1 and os.path.exists('./saved/' + model_name):
            print("\nLoading saved model...")
            model = load_model('./saved/' + model_name)
            print("Model Summary")
            print(model.summary())
        """


        print("\nTraining model...")
        inputs = Input(shape=(self.MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
        embedding = Embedding(input_dim=(len(self.WORD_INDEX) + 1), output_dim=self.EMBEDDING_DIM,
                                weights=[embedding_matrix],
                                input_length=self.MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)(inputs)

        X = keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D(0.3)(embedding)

        X = keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(64, return_sequences = True))(X)  

        #X2 = keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.CuDNNGRU(128, return_sequences = False))(X)  

        X = keras.layers.Conv1D(32, kernel_size=2, padding='valid', kernel_initializer='normal')(X)           
        X = keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(X)       
        #X = Attention(self.MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)(X)

        X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
        X = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(X)
        X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
        X = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(X)

        output = Dense(units=self.LABEL_COUNT, activation='sigmoid')(X)

        model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output, name='intent_classifier')
        print("Model Summary")
        print(model.summary())

        cbk = OutputObserver(model, classifier)
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                          optimizer='adam',
                          metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(x, y,
                      batch_size=30,
                      epochs=23,
                      verbose=2,
                      callbacks = [cbk])


        #keras.utils.vis_utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)

        return model

    def tag_question(self, model, question):

        question = self.clean_str(question)
        question_encoded = [[self.WORD_INDEX[w] for w in question.split(' ') if w in self.WORD_INDEX]]
        question_encoded_padded = pad_sequences(question_encoded, maxlen=self.MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, padding='post')
        predictions = model.predict(question_encoded_padded)

        possible_tags = []
        for i, probability in enumerate(predictions[0]):
            if probability >= 0.01:
                possible_tags.append([self.LABEL_ENCODER.classes_[i], probability])

        possible_tags.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[1]) #sort in place on the basis of the probability in each sub-list in descending order
        print(possible_tags)


    def setup_classifier(self, table):
        '''

        '''
        print("Loading Data Set...")
        x, y = self.loader_encoder(table)

        embeddings_index = self.load_embeddings()

        print("\nGenerating embedding matrix...")
        embedding_matrix = self.create_embedding_matrix(embeddings_index)

        #Loading / Training model
        model = self.sentence_classifier_cnn(embedding_matrix, x, y, table, load_saved=1)

        return model, embeddings_index

    def connect_to_db(self):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", database="questiondb")
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        return mydb, cursor
```

As you can see, I've used a callback to print my predictions after each step.
I've tried to predict labels for all kinds of questions but I get good results only for questions that fall under one category.

For instance,

```
classifier.tag_question(model, "how many days before new year?")
```

gives

```
[['numeric', 0.99226487]]
```

as the output. But a more complex question like

```
classifier.tag_question(model, "who is the prophet of the muslim people and  where is india located and how much do fruits costs there?")
```

gives something like

```
[['human', 0.9990531]]
```

as the output although labels like 'location' and 'numeric' are also relevant.
I used a callback to predict the prediction for that question after every epoch and I see something like this.

```
Epoch 1/23
 - 19s - loss: 0.6581 - acc: 0.6365
[['human', 0.69752634], ['location', 0.40014982], ['entity', 0.32047516], ['abbreviation', 0.23877779], ['numeric', 0.23324837], ['description', 0.15995058]]
Epoch 2/23
 - 12s - loss: 0.4525 - acc: 0.8264
[['human', 0.7437608], ['location', 0.18141672], ['entity', 0.14474556], ['numeric', 0.09171515], ['description', 0.053900182], ['abbreviation', 0.05283475]]
Epoch 3/23
 - 12s - loss: 0.3854 - acc: 0.8478
[['human', 0.86335427], ['location', 0.12673976], ['entity', 0.09847507], ['numeric', 0.064431995], ['description', 0.035599917], ['abbreviation', 0.02441895]]
Epoch 4/23
 - 12s - loss: 0.3634 - acc: 0.8509
[['human', 0.90795004], ['location', 0.10085008], ['entity', 0.09804481], ['numeric', 0.050411616], ['description', 0.032810867], ['abbreviation', 0.014970899]]
Epoch 5/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.3356 - acc: 0.8582
[['human', 0.8365586], ['entity', 0.1130701], ['location', 0.10253032], ['numeric', 0.039931685], ['description', 0.02874279]]
Epoch 6/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.3142 - acc: 0.8657
[['human', 0.95577633], ['entity', 0.088555306], ['location', 0.055004593], ['numeric', 0.015950901], ['description', 0.01428318]]
Epoch 7/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.2942 - acc: 0.8750
[['human', 0.89538944], ['entity', 0.130977], ['location', 0.06350105], ['description', 0.023014158], ['numeric', 0.019377537]]
Epoch 8/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.2739 - acc: 0.8802
[['human', 0.9725125], ['entity', 0.061141968], ['location', 0.026945814], ['description', 0.010931551]]
Epoch 9/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.2579 - acc: 0.8914
[['human', 0.9797143], ['entity', 0.042518377], ['location', 0.027904237]]
Epoch 10/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.2380 - acc: 0.9020
[['human', 0.7897601], ['entity', 0.14315197], ['location', 0.07439863], ['description', 0.019453615], ['numeric', 0.010681627]]
Epoch 11/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.2250 - acc: 0.9104
[['human', 0.9886158], ['entity', 0.024878502], ['location', 0.015951043]]
Epoch 12/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.2131 - acc: 0.9178
[['human', 0.9677731], ['entity', 0.03698206], ['location', 0.026153017]]
Epoch 13/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.2029 - acc: 0.9204
[['human', 0.9514474], ['entity', 0.053581357], ['location', 0.029657435]]
Epoch 14/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.1915 - acc: 0.9285
[['human', 0.9706739], ['entity', 0.0328649], ['location', 0.013876333]]
Epoch 15/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.1856 - acc: 0.9300
[['human', 0.9328136], ['location', 0.05573874], ['entity', 0.025918543]]
Epoch 16/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.1802 - acc: 0.9318
[['human', 0.9895527], ['entity', 0.014941782], ['location', 0.011972391]]
Epoch 17/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.1717 - acc: 0.9373
[['human', 0.9426272], ['entity', 0.03754583], ['location', 0.023379702]]
Epoch 18/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.1614 - acc: 0.9406
[['human', 0.99186605]]
Epoch 19/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.1573 - acc: 0.9432
[['human', 0.9926062]]
Epoch 20/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.1511 - acc: 0.9448
[['human', 0.9993554]]
Epoch 21/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.1591 - acc: 0.9426
[['human', 0.9964465]]
Epoch 22/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.1507 - acc: 0.9451
[['human', 0.999688]]
Epoch 23/23
 - 13s - loss: 0.1524 - acc: 0.9436
[['human', 0.9990531]]
```

I've tried varying my parameters hundreds of times, especially my network size, batch size and epochs to try and avoid over-fitting.

I know my question is ridiculously long but I'm running out of patience and any help would be appreciated.

Here's the link to my colab notebook - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EOklUw7efOv69HvWKpuKVy1LSzcvTTCk.

Comment: I am trying to solve multi label text classification for my thesis as well. Did you solve the problem? I checked your code you have not implemented attention mechanism. Did you drop it? I know this comment may not be helpful in solving your problem. But I was looking for some advice.